# Prove limit ${a_n}^{b_n}$, using definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let assume that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are two convergent real sequences.
Prove that if $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $a_n >0$ and $a_n$ and $b_n$ both have finite limits $a$ and $b$ respectively then:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} {a_n}^{b_n} =a^b$$

Task is to prove it without continiuity, as on the Analysis course we're before the definition of limit of function. Given teacher asked for such a proof I assume it is possibile, but I'm just not competent enough.

Edit:
We defined: 
$$a^{\frac{p}{q}} = \sqrt[q]{a^p}$$
for $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and if $x$ is irrational $a^x$ is a limit of $a^{\frac{p_n}{q_n}}$ where $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ is obtained from $x$ by cutting its decimal expansion at n-th place.

I already proved other theorems of algebra of limits, I tried using triangle inequality to obtain:
 $$| a_n^{b_n} -a^b | < | {a_n}^{b_n} - {a_n}^b | + | {a_n}^b - a^b |$$ but I have problem evaluating first term since $b_n$ can be an arbitrary real number.

I went trough a couple of textbooks namely those by: F.Leja, G.M.Fichtenholz, K. Maurin, but they all use continiuity of $e^x$ and $\log(x)$.
I looked over close to twenty pages of topics on this site and found an argument with continiuity quite a few times.
By the way, for me searching for an expression ${a_n}^{b_n}$ is impossible, because I get result as if I was typing $a_nb_n$.

Wish you Marry Christmas or Happy Holiday, and thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Proof without continuity? It depends, for how do you define the exponent? Some author defines it as to be $e^{b\log a}$ for $a^{b}$, in this case, the continuity of $e^{\cdot}$ (or $\exp$ formally) is indispensable.

Anyway, if we assume the continuity of $\exp$ and $\log$, the proof can be like, $\exp(b_{n}\log a_{n})\rightarrow\exp(b\log a)$.

Comment: Nitpick: We are also assuming the continuity of the product.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right.

Comment: Defining $e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1+x/n)^n$ or $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$, it is not immediately apparent that $e$ is continuous.

Comment: The point is that, OP didn't say anything about the definition.