# How to prove that $ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^{b_n} = \left( \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

By looking around the internet I came across a document, written by someone who teaches mathematical analysis, where it is reported the following result without proof:

If $a_n$  and $b_n$ are two sequences such that $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$ as $n\to\infty$, then

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}  a_n^{b_n}= \left( \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n}$$

I have never seen such a result in a texbook among the usual theorems on limits. Is it true and, if so, how to show it?

Comment: Write $a_n^{b_n}=e^{b_n\ln a_n}$ and use the continuity of the exponential and log functions.

Comment: @StefanLafon That could be an idea, but what if I want to show it without knowing about continuity of functions. Sequences are usually presented first in textbooks and then comes continuity of functions.

Comment: Note that this can only be equality in the sense of an identity since the expression on the right-hand side is undefined if $a = b = 0$ even in cases where the limit on the left-hand side exists.

Comment: @P.Giuliani One way or another, you'll have to use the continuity of those functions, if anything, implicitly. This is exactly what this identity means, that the exponential and log functions are continuous. If you take $a_n$ to be constant, it says that the exponential is continous. If you take $b_n$ to be constant, it says the log is continous.

Comment: It is technically a theorem, but only with a bunch of caveats stated. For example, $a_n\gt0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\gt0$ are necessary for the theorem to hold. Otherwise, the lefthand side is not well-defined, since $0$ is not in the domain of $\ln.$

Comment: @EricTowers Most discussions I have read on the subject conclude that $0^0=1,$ so your claim would be false. But regardless of that, it would still need to be true that the equation is not necessarily true if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0,$ because then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(a_n)$ does not exist.

Comment: I have just found out that the same question was asked here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3485900/prove-limit-a-nb-n-using-definition?rq=1

Comment: @Angel : [Zero to the power of zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero): "Zero to the power of zero, denoted by $0^0$, is a mathematical expression with no agreed-upon value. The most common possibilities are 1 or leaving the expression undefined, with justifications existing for each, depending on context."  In analysis, the more common convention is to leave it undefined (just like other [indeterminate forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms)).

Comment: @P.Giuliani if you insist on a proof that doesn't require continuity, then you'll need to somehow give a reasonable definition of the expression $x^y$ when $y$ is irrational. This is usually done by defining $x^y=\exp(y\ln x)$, but since you want to avoid appealing to continuity, you'll inevitably need to avoid these functions too.

Comment: @EricTowers To start with, there is no rigorous definition of what constitutes an indeterminate form. In analysis, there is no particular mathematical object called by that name. The label "indeterminate form" is a rule-of-thumb heuristic used by teachers in the classroom, but it does not refer to a mathematical concept that I am aware of. Also, I have read the Wikipedia article before, at least 15 times, and I do not understand why people think it supports the idea that $0^0$ is undefined. It does not. The article describes the argument in favor of that position... but then also...

Comment: @EricTowers ...describes the counterarguments and presents the arguments for why $0^0=1$ is more reasonable. So I honestly fail to understand why this is supposed to be convincing. In any case, even if $0^0$ were undefined, that would not get to the root of the explanation for why this theorem needs caveats. As I explained, the caveat is in the fact that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0,$ then regardless of what $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ is, it is the case that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(a_n)$ does not exist.